# In a class 80% of students like coffee; 60% students like both tea and coffee. What percentage of students who like coffee also like tea?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

In a class $80\%$ of students like coffee; $60\%$ students like both tea and coffee. What percentage of students who like coffee also like tea ?

**My Progress, So far**

Total Number of Student in class  $= X$
who like like coffee $= 80\%$
who like both tea and coffee $= 60\%$ 
Percentage pf students who like coffee also like tea $= y\%$
$= \frac{60}{100} \times y$
$= 0.6y$

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag and read its wiki. What progress have you made with this problem?

Comment: Hello, This is for my class work. I am new at StackExchange, I am not sure about Self-study tag and how to use that.

Comment: click on the edit button, and the section with Tags, start typing "self" and self-study should pop up, while you are at it, can you edit to include your attempt as well?

Comment: I just added a tag that should give a bit of a hint. I suggest writing out the conditional probability formula, even if you just copy a generic formula from your textbook or Wikipedia. Then someone can help you with filling in the numbers from your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Once you let the total number of students be $x$ you can compute how many students like coffee. That would be $C=0.8x$

Similarly, you can compute how many students like both coffee and tea: call this quantity $B$.

The desired quantity is $\frac{B}{C}\times 100 \%$.

Your final answer should be a number independent of any variable.

Comment: total number of student be x

Student likes coffee  C=0.8x
Student Like coffee+Tea = B                        


To compute the desired quantity, b/0.8x*100%

Comment: is everything alright? can you first express $B$ in terms of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

We’re to take it as given that we’re interested in students who like coffee, so given that a student likes coffee, what is the probability that the student also likes tea? This is conditional probability.

$$P(\text{tea}\vert\text{coffee}) = \dfrac{P(\text{tea AND coffee})}{P(\text{coffee})}$$

We want to know the quantity on the left. We have both quantities on the right.

Can you fill in the numbers and then relate this to the post by Siong Thye Goh?

(The number of students in the class does not matter.)

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of questions, imagining the class size to be 100 people can be helpful. Then, categorize students based on their choice of drink and which should give you the number of students in data subsets.